# C# cannot implicitly convert type when types are the same

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I have a generic class:

```
public abstract class ModelSet<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IModelObject where T : ModelObject, new(){

    public static ModelSet<T> Lookup(long pObjectId){
       return (ModelObjectMap.Get(pObjectId) as ModelSet<T>);
   }
}
```

I have the following class instantiation of the type using a  class Movement defined as:

```
class Movement : ModelObject.

public partial class Movements : ModelSet<Movement>
```

The following code won't compile due to

> cannot implicitly convert type `ModelSet<Movement>` to `Movements`. An explicit conversion exists.

```
Movements X = Movements.Lookup(12345);
```

Surely, they are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Surely, they are the same.

No, they're not the same. One is `Movements`, and the other is `ModelSet<Movement>`. While every `Movements` instance is an instance of `ModelSet<Movement>`, it's *entirely* possible to have a `ModelSet<Movement>` which isn't a `Movements`... and your method's return type only says that it will return a `ModelSet<T>`.

We have no idea what `ModelObjectMap.Get(pObjectId)` actually does, but it could definitely return a `ModelSet<Movement>` instance which isn't a `Movements`.

We don't know what you need to do with the return value, but you could certainly write:

```
ModelSet<Movement> X = Movements.Lookup(12345);
```

... although it's worth noting that the `Movements` class actually isn't involved in that call at all; it would actually be compiled to:

```
ModelSet<Movement> X = ModelSet<Movement>.Lookup(12345);
```